# Simulate a click with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

After 5 seconds, I need to simulate a click on a button.

```
var count = 5;
countdown = setInterval(function () {
    $("#count").html(count);
    if (count == 0) {
        alert("Jotain pitäis tapahtua. kai");
        //What should I put instead of this line?
    }
    count--;
}, 1000);
return false;
```

Is it even possible?

Comment: $(targetelement).click()

Comment: `setInterval`'s second parameter is in milliseconds, so it should be `1000*5`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
$("#button").click();
```

This triggerses all the event handlers for click event that have been added to the button.Event handlers must have been added by the same instance of jQuery that triggers the click event ( be careful if you have more than one instance of jQuery )

if you want to trigger some namespaced effect use

```
$("#button").trigger('click.namespace');
```

Comment: Yes, but you can only use this technique to trigger the JavaScript code that runs when a button is clicked. For security reasons, it's impossible to open a link via JavaScript-click.

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen yes, this triggers the click event. Of course if you have added click event handlers with that instance of jquery

Comment: @Blazemonger yes the idea is that you triggere event handlers associated with the click event

Answer (score 6):

`$('#my_button').trigger('click');`

That ought to do it for you.

Or as others have posted the shorthand:

`$('#my_button').click();`

Comment: trigger is definitely the way to do it

Comment: @josh internally `.click()` calls `.trigger('click')` so it's the same

Comment: Anyone know why these things don't work within a jsfiddle? They only work if you already have an established (in this case) `.click event created`. If it is a simple `<a href="www.com">` it doesn't work

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS it works in jsFiddle but it only fires the jQuery click event bound to it. If you have a link that goes to a URL you cannot trigger it this way.

Comment: Yeah that's what I figured, annoying you can't. I have other silly ways to do that scenario.

Comment: @josh yes of course it runs faster, it's one less function call :)

Answer (score 2):

From jQuery's .click() documentation:

`Description: Bind an event handler to the "click" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.`

Answer (score 2):

why dont you try setTimeout()?

```
$("targetElement").on("click", function(){
setTimeout(function(){
    //do something
},1000);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible, and you appear to be very close to having a complete answer. Try this:

```
var count = 5;

setInterval(function () {
    $("#count").html(count);
    if (count == 0) {
        alert("Jotain pitäis tapahtua. kai");
        $('#myButton').click();        
    }
    count--;
}, 1000);
```

I just added `$('#myButton').click();` to click the button.

Comment: It's 1000 because I want it to countdown :)

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen That doesn't jive with `After 5 seconds,`